# how to set the folder of destination when I use local copy?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a project in Visual Studio 2010 and in this project I have a "lib" foleder in which I have the external dll that I need. In this case, the libraries of SQLite.

Well, I can set hte reference to the principal dlls, SQLite.dll and SQLite.Linq.dll. In this case, the dll are copy in the main folder of the application.

However, I need also the SQLiteinterop.dll. I have tried to add a reference to this dll, but I get the error that it is not a valid COM component. So the way that I find to copy the dll is marked as local copy in the properties of the dll that is in the "lib" folder.

However, this copies the dll in a subfolder "lib" in the main application folder and I need to copy in the main folder.

Is there any way to set in visual studio where to copy each dll?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Build Event, retrievable in the Properties of the Project.

Here you can make a Post-build event which copies the file to the Build folder.

Something like:

```
copy /Y "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName)\sqllitefile.dll" "$(TargetDir)\$(ProjectName)\sqllitefile.dll"
```